# Can't make Loop on Excel VBA and print results

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

I am new to Excel VBA and I want to calculate the distance between two atoms and make a loop to calculate it for all wanted cases

with coordinate B(i), C(i), D(i) in the Excel sheet correspond to **x,y,z** cartesian coordinate..

these atoms are located : One in a row (i) and the other in a row (i+5)

I write this algorithm but I cant transfer it to excel VBA

```
For i=4 to 1000
    For j=9 to 1000

    d=SQRT(POWER(B(i)-B(j),2)+  POWER(C(i)-C(j),2)+  POWER(D(i)-D(j),2))

    print **d** in (P(i)) #want to print the distance **d** in a case
    j=j+4   # **j** is a multiple of 4
    i=i+4   # **i** is a multiple of 4

next i
```

Thanks, this is my first question

Comment: you mean `Debug.Print` to immediate window ? or `MsgBox` ?

Comment: So you have 997 atoms and you want to calculate the distance of each of the first 992 atoms with the atom which is 5 atoms forward? By `B(i)` do you mean the ith element of column B? What do you want to do with these distances? Dump them to column E?

Comment: yes I want to dump them in column E

Comment: I want to calculate the distance between atom 4 and all atoms 9,13,17,21 .....                                                                                              and then go to atom 8 and calculate the distance between it and atoms 13,17,21....

Comment: Why use VBA at all if that is what you want? Distance squared is a built-in function and runs using optimized C code.

Comment: I can open my data file excel (that's why I am using it), and there is double loop... can I run for loop without VBA?  .. thanks

Comment: You want the distances from atom 4 in column E, the distances from atom 8 in column F, the distances for atom 12 in column G, etc.?

Comment: yes the number of distances will be very large 250*250.. I will give it more time to explain it well .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the following should work for you:

```
Sub FindDistances()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim r As Long, c As Long 'row and column indices for output
    Dim data As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'useful when doing a lot of writing

    data = Range("B4:D1000").Value 'data is a 1-based array

    c = 5 'column E

    For i = 1 To UBound(data) - 5 Step 4
        r = 1 'first row printed in -- adjust if need be
        For j = i + 5 To UBound(data) Step 4
            Cells(r, c).Value = Sqr((data(i, 1) - data(j, 1)) ^ 2 + (data(i, 2) - data(j, 2)) ^ 2 + (data(i, 3) - data(j, 3)) ^ 2)
            r = r + 1
        Next j
        c = c + 1
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I want. I am calculating the possibility of one atom to make bond with one the rest... the distance should be in a range 1.1-1.4... I know that I have to calculate the opposite also..i.e the last one with the rest for example... I will sort it out.. thank you very much.. I have been waiting for months for my co-worker to do his task -this task-

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? In VBA, you refer to cells like `Cells(row, column)`. Data is supposed to be located in a worksheet named `Sheet1`. I'm calculating each dimension separately (`d1, d2, d3`) just for reading simplicity. You can merge those four lines in one if you like. **EDIT:** reading your comments above, I add a nested loop (j).

```
Sub Distances()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim d1 As Double, d2 As Double, d3 As Double, d As Double

    For i = 4 To 1000 Step 4 'Can't understand your data, but Step 4 tries to account for your j=j+4 and i=i+4
        For j = 9 To 1000 Step 4
            d1 = (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2) - Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 2)) ^ 2
            d2 = (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3) - Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 3)) ^ 2
            d3 = (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4) - Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 4)) ^ 2
            d = Sqr(d1 + d2 + d3)
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 16).Value = d
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you CMArg, I will use this script to build mine, and tell

Comment: See edition in my previous answer. And let me know if it helps you.

Comment: the script is working fine, thank you very much .. as you see I have modified the algorithm lately to print over i and j.. my bad. Mr John helped me for that.. thank you again

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub AtomDistance()
'
' AtomDistance Macro1
'

'
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim Distance As Double

Dim Column As String
Column = InputBox("Which column you want to print results(put a letter)?")
Dim MyCell11 As String
Dim MyCell12 As String
Dim MyCell13 As String

Dim MyCell21 As String
Dim MyCell22 As String
Dim MyCell23 As String

Dim MyCell3 As String
j = 9
For i = 4 To 12

MyCell3 = Column & i

MyCell11 = "B" & i
MyCell12 = "C" & i
MyCell13 = "D" & i

MyCell21 = "B" & j
MyCell22 = "C" & j
MyCell23 = "D" & j

Distance = (((Range(MyCell11).Value - Range(MyCell21).Value) ^ 2) + ((Range(MyCell12).Value - Range(MyCell22).Value) ^ 2) + ((Range(MyCell13).Value - Range(MyCell23).Value) ^ 2)) ^ 0.5


If i Mod 4 = 0 Or j Mod 4 = 0 Then

    Range(MyCell3).Value = Distance
End If

j = j + 1

Next i
```